# plyr rename function not working

Tags: r

I can't figure out why this version of plyr's `rename` function isn't working.

I have a dataframe where I have a single column that ends up being named `seq(var_slcut_trucknumber_min, var_slcut_trucknumber_max)` because I made it like this:

```
df_metbal_slcut <- as.data.frame(seq(var_slcut_trucknumber_min,var_slcut_trucknumber_max))
```

The terms `var_slcut_trucknumber_min` and `var_slcut_trucknumber_max` are defined as the min and max of another column.

However, when trying to rename it by the following code,

```
var_temp <- names(df_metbal_slcut)
df_metbal_slcut <- rename(df_metbal_slcut, c(var_temp="trucknumber"))
```

I get an error as follows:

```
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: var_temp
```

I don't understand why.  I know that I can easily do this as `colnames(df_metbal_slcut)[1] <- "trucknumber"`, but I'm an R n00b, and I was looking at a data manipulation tutorial that said that learning plyr was the way to go, so here I am stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
df_metbal_slcut <- rename(df_metbal_slcut, setNames("trucknumber",var_temp))
```

The reason it wasn't working was that `c(var_temp = "trucknumber")` creates a named vector with the name `var_temp`, which is not what you were intending. When creating named objects using the `tag = value` syntax, R won't evaluate variables. It assumes that you literally want the name to be `var_temp`.

More broadly, it might make sense to name the column more sensibly when initially creating the data frame again using `setNames`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about setNames.  I tried it as follows and it works.  `setNames(df_metbal_slcut, c("trucknumber"))`  Thank you kindly for looking at my problem.  I will "check" your answer in 2 minutes when SO allows me to do so.

Comment: A thousand apologies, but it seems that `setNames(df_metbal_slcut, c("trucknumber"))` didn't actually change the name of the column of `df_metbal_slcut`.  When I call up `df_metbal_slcut` with `View(df_metbal_slcut)`, I get the old name for the first column again.  Is `setNames` meant to be used within a plyr function and not on its own?

Comment: @ReubenMathew Like most anything in R, you have to assign the result to something. `setNames` doesn't modify anything in place. e.g. `df_metbal_slcut <- setnames(...)`.

Comment: OK.  I was confused because using `setNames` brought up the `df_metbal_slcut` dataframe in the console with the first column named to `trucknumber`, but as you said, it wasn't assigned to anything.  I will watch for that in the future.  Thank you again for taking the time to answer my questions.  It's much appreciated.