# Error when renaming column values in a data.frame using plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I am having difficulty **renaming** values in a **data.frame** using `plyr`. This appears to be a somewhat common problem, but [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492669/plyr-rename-function-not-working), [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068960/updated-plyr-rename-not-recognizing-identical-x-error-the-following-from) Q/As aren't working for me. I am using `plyr` version: 1.8.4

As noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame-in-r) 108 point thread, the following code *should* work...

*I must be making some simple error, but I don't know where.*

Code:

```
library(plyr)    
df <-plyr::rename(df, c("mod1"="AT", "mod2"="CYP", "mod3"="OA"))
```

**resulting error:** *The following `from` values were not present in `x`: mod1, mod2, mod3*

Other Q/As have said to disregard this error, or to use `setnames()` from the `data.table` package. `setnames()` results in an error, as does dplyr's `rename` function. The issue is also definitely not due to loading both `dplyr` and `plyr`.

This solution from the another thread also doesn't appear to change anything:

```
names(df)[names(df) == 'mod1'] <- 'AT'
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(dose = c(0.5, 0.565608284362011, 0.639825462677876,0.723781164472726, 0.818753245381915, 0.5, 0.565608284362011,0.639825462677876, 0.723781164472726, 0.818753245381915, 0.926187236872587,0.5, 0.565608284362011, 0.639825462677876, 0.723781164472726,0.818753245381915, 0.926187236872587), p1 = c(0.0103075076812739,0.0116952370538794, 0.0132672958208565, 0.0150474513444454, 0.017062331184752,0.0103075076812739, 0.0116952370538794, 0.0132672958208565, 0.0150474513444454,0.017062331184752, 0.0193417088954045, 0.0103075076812739, 0.0116952370538794,0.0132672958208565, 0.0150474513444454, 0.017062331184752, 0.0193417088954045), pmin1 = c(0.00536333319279742, 0.00625496575175793, 0.00728840578671532,0.00848520965537471, 0.00987000073136779, 0.00536333319279742,0.00625496575175793, 0.00728840578671532, 0.00848520965537471,0.00987000073136779, 0.0114708496853662, 0.00536333319279742,0.00625496575175793, 0.00728840578671532, 0.00848520965537471,0.00987000073136779, 0.0114708496853662), pmax1 = c(0.0152516821697505,0.0171355083560008, 0.0192461858549976, 0.0216096930335161, 0.0242546616381362,0.0152516821697505, 0.0171355083560008, 0.0192461858549976, 0.0216096930335161,0.0242546616381362, 0.0272125681054427, 0.0152516821697505, 0.0171355083560008,0.0192461858549976, 0.0216096930335161, 0.0242546616381362, 0.0272125681054427), model = c("mod1", "mod1", "mod1", "mod1", "mod1", "mod2","mod2", "mod2", "mod2", "mod2", "mod2", "mod3", "mod3", "mod3","mod3", "mod3", "mod3")), .Names = c("dose", "p1", "pmin1", "pmax1","model"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 101L, 102L, 103L,104L, 105L, 106L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is incredibly strange for me, because I believe this code was previously working for me!

Comment: Look at your data; they're not names, they're values in the `model` variable.

Comment: I understand - but how can I change all of the strings named "mod1" in the model column to something else?

I am nearly certain this code worked a week ago.

Comment: There are lots of options, but you're already sort of built for a lookup table: `df$new_variable <- c("mod1"="AT", "mod2"="CYP", "mod3"="OA")[df$model]` If it worked before, your data must have been in a wider format.

Comment: Another option: `dplyr::recode(df$model, "mod1"="AT", "mod2"="CYP", "mod3"="OA")`

Comment: @ alistaire, this solution works great ~  if you were to post it as an answer I would accept it.  @ kitman0804 , I've tried your solution as well, but it appears to not change the original file, and when applying the solution to my true data, received some errors that recode cannot be applied to a data.frame